# Entity Framework Subquery with ANY

Tags: c#, entity-framework

please I need help
am trying to do this with entity framework but I don't know how to do it.

```
SELECT * FROM PJT.Notifications
WHERE ProjectProgrssID = ANY(
SELECT ProjectProgressID FROM PJT.ProjectProgress
WHERE ProjectID = ANY(
SELECT ProjectID FROM PJT.Projects WHERE UniversityID = 1))
```

Comment: am sorry "ACB" but i didn't knew how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Projects.Where(p => p.UniversityId = 1)
    .SelectMany(pp => pp.ProjectProgress)
    .SelectMany(pr => pr.Notifications);
```

Comment: it's working , but i thought that i need ANY to make it work , could you please tell me what select many do ??

Comment: You have to take a different approach using entity-linq then when querying your database. In SQL you have to select your records and narrow it down from detail to the higher level.  Entity provides an easyer acces where you can provide your higher level entities and select down from there.